# Is there any way to get two-weapon style for dual weapon attack?

Tags: dnd-4e, ranger, two-weapon-fighting

Is there any way possible to get the scout's two-weapon style for the purposes of using dual weapon attack as a class other than scout? Is there any way a ranger or other class can get it through hybridization, multi-classing, or feats such as Martial Readiness, Skill Swap, etc?

I've been looking at Martial Readiness, but I don't think it will work because dual weapon attack seems like it is actually a class feature. I looked at maybe a hybrid scout, but there doesn't seem to be an option for that. Is this just impossible? Is there a way to just get the dual weapon attack without the two-weapon style?

Comment: Are you trying to get Dual Weapon Attack or Two-Weapon Style or both?

Comment: Mainly Dual Weapon Attack is what I'm after.

Answer (score 2):

After tooling around in Character Builder, I've determined that you can't get the Dual Weapon Attack power as anything other than a non-hybrid Scout. It seems to be because it's part of a class feature, rather than a standalone at-will power. And since Scout doesn't even have a hybrid or multiclass option, you can't get it via Hybrid Talent or even paragon multiclassing.

This is probably an issue of balance, as the Essentials line of classes (including the Scout) weren't really designed to work with the beefy encounter powers of non-Essentials classes; their bread and butter is basic attacks, which non-Essentials classes barely use.

At a glance, Dual Weapon Attack seems way better than the ranger's other go-to TWF attack, Twin Strike, so it's probably for the best that you can only use DWA under controlled circumstances.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I am aware of to get Dual Weapon Attack is to be any non-Ranger class, and multiclass into Ranger then at level 11 choose Paragon Multiclassing as your Paragon Path. One of the level 11 features of this path is:

> At 11th level, you can choose to replace one of your at-will powers with an at-will power from your second class.

Unlike many other abilities like this (such as the Human and Half-Elf racial abilities that grant extra at-will powers) this does not specify that the at-will power must be a level 1 power. Therefore you are able to use any at-will power from that class which for Ranger includes Dual Weapon Attack. (Note: If you are using the Character Builder it has a bug where it only allows for level 1 attack powers to be selected, since Dual Weapon Attack doesn't have a level it doesn't show up, but is still a valid choice)

The only way to get Two-Weapon Style is to be an actual Scout since there is not a multiclass feat that grants it, nor a hybrid version of the Scout.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is one way to gain Dual Weapon Attack as any class, provided that your DM agrees to using the Unearthed Arcana Multiclass rules from Dragon Magazine #421, page 26.

Copy-pasted text follows:

> **Dragon Magazine #421, pag 30**
>   Several levels in ranger, whether primary or secondary,
>   provide the opportunity to choose among
>   alternatives. A character who has the primary class
>   of ranger and the hunter build or scout build already
>   gains similar benefits and can ignore these options.

Specifically about the Dual Weapon Attack option (emphasis mine):

> When you take 9th level in the ranger class, instead
>   of choosing a daily attack power, you can gain either
>   the Close Combat Archery class feature or the
>   *dual weapon attack power*. If you do so, you cannot
>   replace the selected option at later levels.

On the other hand, i do not know of any way to get the Two Weapon Style feature as anything other than a non-hybrid Scout.